# Create Optional Parameters in Generic Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

By itself, I did not quite deal with typescript issues, but more than once I came across such a need for generic types with different arguments, since I do not quite understand this topic so deeply, I decided to leave the question
The task looks simple:

```
interface sampelType{
    typeOne: (arg1:number,arg2:customType) => 0 | Promise<any>
    typeTwo: (arg1:string) => 0 | Promise<any>
    typeThree: () => 0 | Promise<any>
}
```

And I would like to achieve this opportunity:

```
const caseOne:sampelType<number,customType>;
const caseTwo:sampelType<string>;
const caseThree:sampelType;
```

> The generic type "sampelType" requires the following number of type arguments: 1.

I would like to implement such a type feature rather, but I don’t understand how it is possible to make an optional type, possibly overloading, but I haven’t found a way yet:

```
type simpelType<T1, T2> = (arg1?: T1, arg2?: T2) => 0 | Promise<any>;
```

That's probably all, I will be glad to any advice or views of other approaches for clean code in TypeScript

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands your question is missing some crucial details that would make it possible for us to help you. In particular, your "sampelType" does not take any type arguments as written and your interface doesn't match your description. As far as I can tell (and again it isn't clear what you're asking) this is probably a better case for [an overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)  than a generic.

Comment: I edited the question, I think I conveyed the meaning of the task, thanks for your feedback

Comment: *Much* better, thanks! Please do take the tour and read how to ask though, they will help you in future interactions on the site. So back to overloads v generics, do you need to work with any arbitrary types or just the signatures you posted originally?

Comment: I would like to understand how to overload a type so that there can be two or more required ones. And also 0 or 2 arguments.
These are the cases most often encountered in the project.
I will definitely read and familiarize myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the general case, you can make generics optional by giving them defaults:

```js
type simpelType<T1 = string | number, T2 = {}> = (arg1?: T1, arg2?: T2) => 0 | Promise<any>;
```

but based on what your example code looks like you probably want something more like this:

```js
function foo(): 0 | Promise<any>
function foo(x: string): 0 | Promise<any>
function foo<T>(x: number, y: T): 0 | Promise<any>
function foo<T>(x?: string | number, y?: T): 0 | Promise<any> {
  // do stuff
  return 0
}

foo()           // fine, matches overload 1
foo('hi')       // fine, matches overload 2
foo(3, true)    // fine, matches overload 3 T is inferred as boolean

foo(3)          // error!
foo('hi', true) // error!
```

sorry the syntax highlighting is a little off, but that's a known bug in highlight.js which is what Stack Overflow uses for syntax highlighting.

Note that although the compiler will ensure type-safety by resolving to a specific overload, your code will still have to figure out which one you got in the function body:

```js
function foo(): 0 | Promise<any>
function foo(x: string): 0 | Promise<any>
function foo<T>(x: number, y: T): 0 | Promise<any>
function foo<T>(x?: string | number, y?: T): 0 | Promise<any> {
  if (typeof x === 'number') {
    // here you know y exists and you're in overload #3
  } else if (typeof x === 'string') {
    // here you are in overload #2
  } else { // no arguments
    // overload #1
  }
  return 0
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAEpGIBQEoBcKAGFAHxQAUAnRAW3gGcBTAHgENIBPAPjCjiVXRYAHvjqwK8SAHM8hEuSq1GrDtwgwEyNBiYAVTphEpI4agCMGFADQp2+XbKKlKNeszZceG-tsR6DQgD8ouKSUvIm5pY27MEoDvhOCq7KHpwoAN7AKCgA9LkoACaIKGLgoKDZKBQMsOAUqATAAL4ggjhgGJgA5AAW8N3YnVgAzDbi4AxDw5gjQ+19A+MUk0NAA)